# Insert record in table with constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why do I get an error when trying to add records to a PostGres table, and how to solve this:

```
INSERT INTO common.levels(level_pid, level_name) VALUES(0,'Level1')
```

Heres the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS common.levels
(
  level_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  level_pid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  level_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_MT_Parent FOREIGN KEY (level_pid) REFERENCES common.levels(level_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Error:

[image: Here's the error]

Comment: looks to me as if you want to reference another row in the same table (via level_pid which needs to match an existing level_id).  That won't be the case on the first row to be inserted.  The error detail message is actually quite explicit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FK constraint that you have created specifies that the level_pid must already exist as a level_id in this table. Hence,  when you are inserting the value 'Level1'  this does not exist as a level_id in the table and inserting would therefore violate the FK constraint. I would suggest creating the table, inserting all the required initial data and then inserting the FK constraint afterwards. Note that data must be inserted in a way that eventually each level_pid corresponds to a level_id in the table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped! It was also possible to add the constraint from the beginning and then add a "root" level with level_id 0 and level_pid NULL. So it works now.